# How to suppress warnings from particular dll

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll, lotus-notes

I am adding 3rd party Lotus Notes dll in my project which is not CLS-Compliant. I need to set 'Treat Warning As Error'. How can I suppress all the warnings from that particular dll only.

All warnings are like

```
Identifier 'Domino.Name_Of_Identifier' is not CLS-compliant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't suppress warnings from a particular DLL - but you can turn off specific warnings.

In the message you'll see a number like CS3008 - go into Project Properties, Build Tab, and enter this into the Suppress Warnings field.

[image: Project Properties, Build Page]

Comment: Thanks Beven, When I added warning numbers to suppress list it gave me error that number CS3008 is not valid warning number.. Can you please tell me how to do it. thanks

Comment: You'll need to use the actual number from the particular warning you're trying to suppress.

Comment: i.e. you enter 3008 rather than CS3008

Answer (score 1):

You can disable warnings locally  with [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

To disable [Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28VS.80%29.aspx) warnings, use the following warning numbers:

`40025, 40026, 40027, 40028`

Alternatively you can mark your class or your assemlby as being non-CLS compliant using the [`CLSCompliantAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but in this case I guess it would be like shooting a fly with a gun.

Comment: if at assembly level I add cslcomplience[true] and at local level I said clscompliance[false].. Will global get overriden by local?

Comment: This particular attribute has `Inherited = true`, which means it can be inherited. Yes, you can override locally class, struct, enum, constructor, etc... as you like.

Answer (score 0):

After struggle I found perfect solution. Open Output window and build the solution. You will see the warning. Add this warning to the window shown by Bevan. It works.